# Google Charts - dont link 2 points

Tags: google-visualization, googlevis

I have a line in my Chart that represent a stat that always resets at 8am. Is there anyway I can prevent the Chart from connecting the 2 points in that particular position?

I have not been able to find such setting or property for LineCharts.

The pic shows how my graph looks now (top) and how I want it to look (bottom).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an intermediate row, with a domain value between the two points where you want the non-connection, with null values for some or all of your series values, and then make sure you have `interpolateNulls:false` in your options.  The domain value could be equal to one of your two points.

Alternatively, you could set a style for each segment, using the `role:'style'`, and give any segment an invisible color with `stroke-color:transparent`.  Here is an example that shows this: http://jsfiddle.net/dlaliberte/kyq03g12/

```
// Add a 'style' role column.
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
...
data.addRows([
      [0, 0, '', 80],   
      [1, 10,'', 75],  
      [2, 23, 'stroke-color:transparent',72],
      [3, 44, '', 37]
  ]);
```

Read more about the style role here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks! (used the last option)